# Unable to scrape all product color swatches

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the image url and name of product color shades on Sephora, and am able to get the url and name for all shades except the one currently clicked (which seems default clicked). What am I doing wrong?

Example product: [link](https://www.sephora.com/product/radiant-creamy-concealer-P377873?skuId=2172310&icid2=products%20grid:p377873)

See below code:

```
def get_shade_names(url):
global names_df
driver.get(url)
shade_names = []
shade_items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('css-1ax77m2')
btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('css-ctsnxi')
sleep(2)
btn.click()
sleep(5)
for item in shade_items:
    name_tags = item.find_elements_by_class_name('css-1j1jwa4')
    sleep(2)
    for tag in name_tags:
        shade_name = tag.get_attribute('aria-label')
        sleep(2)
        shade_names.append(shade_name)

names_df = pd.DataFrame(shade_names, columns = ['Shade_name'])
return names_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting default selected shade name because the button has different class name i.e. `class="css-1p28rvx "`

You can try below CSS path to grab all the shade name include default selected one

```
shade_names = []
shade_elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.css-1ax77m2 button')
for element in shade_elements:
    shade_name = element.get_attribute('aria-label')
    shade_names.append(shade_name)

print(len(shade_names))
print(shade_names)
```